# How to require password to terminate a userform in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, userform

I want to prevent the user from closing the form and editing the spreadsheet if they don't know the password. I can get the Userform to stay open but I cannot figure out how to initialize the form so all of the command buttons still function.

I have tried using an if statement as described below. The userform stays open but isn't initialized so the user is unable to enter a password or run the userform at all.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()

    Password = InputBox("Enter Password")
    If Password = "syntax" Then
        UserForm1.Hide
    ElseIf Password <> "syntax" Then
        UserForm1.Show
    End If
    End

End Sub
```

There aren't any error messages, but if the VBA editor window isn't open the user has to close Excel completely. Any advice on what to try next is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no real way to prevent a userform from being closed. Password or not, all a user has to do is press Ctrl + Pause/Break and the code breaks, with the option to debug or end.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Is there a way to make the Userform pop back up (initialized) in this If statement though? Just trying to make it as "difficult" as possible for the average Excel user to close the form.

Comment: You would need an `Exit Sub` under `.Show` to prevent the form from terminating

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs When I use `Exit Sub` under `.Show` the userform shows up but is still not initialized

Comment: What do you mean it's not initialized? It should have initialized from the first time the form was opened. The code doesn't run `UserForm_Initialize` again because you are not creating a new instance of the userform when the user fails to terminate due to an incorrect password. If you want to manually run this then type `UserForm_Initialize` inside your If statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UserForm_QueryClose` to intercept all 'close' actions on a userform. This code would go in the userform itself.

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    Dim password As String

    password = InputBox("Enter Password")
    If password = "syntax" Then
        Cancel = False 'If password is correct, allow close event to proceed
    ElseIf password <> "syntax" Then
        Cancel = True 'If password is incorrect, cancel the close event
    End If
End Sub
```

Like K.Dᴀᴠɪs pointed out, this still won't prevent anyone from pausing the code execution and manually closing the form (Excel just doesn't provide that level of security).

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try that next